# Weighting strings to reach different endpoints

Tags: java

I have a program that compares values from different levels. This program is started via the console with program arguments. I load the different levels from a .yaml file. These levels are stored as strings in a list (In reality there are much more than in the example below).

**Example Levels**

> LOCAL (lowest Level), SERVER1, PRODUCTION (highest Level)

My question now is whether there is an easy way to "weight" these levels. What I mean is that if the user takes `LOCAL` as a base and checks `SERVER1`, something else should happen than if it was the other way around.

I know I could do that with a `HashMap<>` (or something else like that) and just set a value and compare it. But before I use it I wanted to ask if there is a better and more clean solution.

Comment: An array/list index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an enum to name the levels. Their value would be a number. The lowest for LOCAL to highest for PRODUCTION.

When you select a new level, you can verify if the new value is higher or lower than the current to generate your action.

Example:

```
public enum Level {
    LOCAL(0), SERVER_ONE(1), PRODUCTION(2);

    private int level;

    Level(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me. But I have another question. Is there a way to generate the enum variables or do I have to "type" each one separately? I have a list in the Java class where all variables are listed.

Comment: Are they dynamically provided by an external event that generates the list? Or do you know them in advance and fill the list?

Comment: I get the list from a website as a .yaml file. But you have to download this file manually.

Comment: I see, and does this file change often or rarely?

I ask because an enum cannot change once you app is running. So if this file doesn't change often, I would suggest you to transform the values into an enum and update it as you get new values in the future. I am guessing you have business logic that depends on this file values, so the enum makes sense.

Comment: The files changes rarely. But the program does not run all the time. The user calls the program and after using it, it closes again. I don't think that the environments are changed in this short time.

Comment: In that case, you are better of with an enum in my opinion. You will only have the advantage of keeping a clean structure that will allow you to differentiate between the levels. When the file changes, you will need code change for sure